# Binary writer inserts extra character in writing

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Hi I am trying to save xml to a file and it keeps adding different character at the start of file.

Code I have is

```
string strCXML2;

strCXML2 = "<input type=" + "\"" + "hidden" + "\"" + " name=" + "\"" + "cxml-urlencoded" + "\"" + " value=" + "\"";
strCXML2 = strCXML2 + "<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM " + "\"" + "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.023/cXML.dtd" + "\"" + ">";

//<snip>

BinaryWriter bw5 = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(Server.MapPath("~/data/test/test19.xml"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))   
bw5.Write(strCXML2); 
bw5.Close();
```

This return following file in xml "}" at start each time it is some other junk character

```
}<input type="hidden" name="cxml-urlencoded" value="<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.023/cXML.dtd">
```

Any ideas why it is doing this?

Comment: try specify encoding in the method there

Comment: where do you accept answers been looking to that but cant seem to find it

Comment: When you're logged in, there is a ghostly tick to the left of each answer of a question you asked.  Click the tick that best answered your question so it turns solid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The characters it is writing is the encoded length of the string, because: it is not expecting to write a text file. `BinaryWriter` writes... *binary*. It is writing the string in an encoded binary way that it can read back with [`BinaryReader.ReadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readstring.aspx).

Instead, use just:

```
File.WriteAllText(path, strCXML2);
```

The `BinaryWriter.Write(string)` method's documentation explains all this:

> A length-prefixed string represents the string length by prefixing to the string a single byte or word that contains the length of that string. This method first writes the length of the string as a UTF-7 encoded unsigned integer, and then writes that many characters to the stream by using the BinaryWriter instance's current encoding.

and, helpfully, links to a separate section about [writing *text* files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `BinaryWriter`, you first encode it in either ASCII or Unicode UTF-16. Your XML should specify what encoding it uses, use that specific encoding for the Binary Writer.

```
byte[] textbyte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);`
```

That should remove the first two junk characters.
I do recommend the `WriteAllText()` method.

Use `Binarywriter` if you need to write in a specific area in the `textfile(offset)`.